# "pip3 list --outdated" item is to keep remaining after "pip3 install -U"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, rst2pdf

I am using `pip3 list --outdated --format=freeze` for bulk update of current installed all packages. 
Recently I noticed one package `rst2pdf` is to keep remaining after `pip3 install -U`.
I am experiencing this issue with MacOS High Sierra and Ubuntu 16.04.

From the point of view of python programming, it is not matter because I can use it.
But from the point of view of system admin, all time package is downloading and it is wasting time and bandwidth.

Is there any way to remove the finished item from `pip3 list --outdated` output?

Here is command output:

```
bash-3.2$ pip3 install -U rst2pdf
Collecting rst2pdf
Requirement already up-to-date: reportlab>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already up-to-date: pdfrw in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already up-to-date: Pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already up-to-date: docutils in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already up-to-date: pillow>=2.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from reportlab>=2.4->rst2pdf)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from reportlab>=2.4->rst2pdf)
Installing collected packages: rst2pdf
  Found existing installation: rst2pdf 0.93.dev0
    Uninstalling rst2pdf-0.93.dev0:
      Successfully uninstalled rst2pdf-0.93.dev0
Successfully installed rst2pdf-0.93.dev0
bash-3.2$ echo $?
0
bash-3.2$ pip3 list --outdated
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
rst2pdf (0.93.dev0) - Latest: 0.93 [sdist]
```

Update: 2018/02/22
When I uninstall rst2pdf and re-install it, I get same result.
Here is bash logs:

```
$ sudo pip3 uninstall rst2pdf
Uninstalling rst2pdf-0.93.dev0:
  /usr/local/bin/rst2pdf
  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rst2pdf-0.93.dev0-py3.5.egg-info
......(snip)....
  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rst2pdf/writer.py
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled rst2pdf-0.93.dev0
$ 
$ sudo pip3 install rst2pdf
  Downloading rst2pdf-0.93.tar.gz (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 706kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already satisfied: reportlab>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already satisfied: Pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already satisfied: pdfrw in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from rst2pdf)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from reportlab>=2.4->rst2pdf)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=2.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from reportlab>=2.4->rst2pdf)
Installing collected packages: rst2pdf
  Running setup.py install for rst2pdf ... done
Successfully installed rst2pdf-0.93.dev0
$
$ pip3 list --outdated
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
rst2pdf (0.93.dev0) - Latest: 0.93 [sdist]
$
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no downloadable packages at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rst2pdf — nothing to update from. You can try to upgrade from https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf.git#egg=rst2pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, when I uninstall rst2pdf and re-install it, I can successfully install it from pypi. Then, pip3 list --outdated result is same.

Comment: Oh, I see, they still have outdated packages at https://pypi.python.org/simple/rst2pdf/

Answer (score 0):

A newer answer for you: rst2pdf is packaged for Python3 so pip should be able to manage it for you just fine.